# Bottomnavigationview hides when switching from a tab with collapsing toolbar

Tags: android

I have a `MainActivity` XML that contains a `bottomNavigationView` (bar) with 5 tabs. Each tab calls a different fragment. Switching from a fragment with a collapsing toolbar in its XML (labelled A in picture) to a fragment with a plain fragment (labelled B in picture) causes the `bottomNavigationView` (bar) to hide partially off the screen.

Is there a way of preventing this?

Screen with fragment containing collapsing toolbar.

[image: Link: screen with fragment containing collapsing toolbar]

Screen of another tab with a plain fragment.

[image: Link: screen of another tab with a plain fragment]

Fragment Class containing code for collapsing toolbar

```
 public class Profile extends Fragment {

    public Profile() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        Toolbar toolbar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("test");

        return rootView;
    }
```

Corresponding xml containing collapsing toolbar code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ani_dog_one"
                android:contentDescription="whut"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Plain fragment class

```
public class Review extends Fragment {

 public Review() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_review, container, false);
        //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_bar_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

XML for plain fragment class contains just a plain FrameLayout

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Intent intent;

private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager;
private android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();          
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();      

    Discover discoverFragment = new Discover();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, discoverFragment, discoverFragment.getTag()).commit();

    setupBottomNavigationView();

}

private void setupBottomNavigationView() {

BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(this, bottomNavigationViewEx);

}

public void goToOptions(MenuItem menu) {

 intent = new Intent(this, Options.class);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

XML for MainActivity

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.android.project_qwer.MainActivity">

    <!-- main fragments goes here -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- bottom navigation view -->
    <com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" >

    </com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Comment: Hey @ben could you please narrow down your problem and only post the code related to the line that you traced down the error? This will greatly help as your post is too long for much users to feel inclined to help.

Comment: Hmm, that is the issue, the programme ran as normal except for that the bottomnavigationview keeps hiding partially every time I tab away from tab A (in picture). This issue occurred right after I added a collapsible toolbar to the fragment of tab A, but there is no associated error message. Thus, I have given all the code that might be related to the problem, and yes I know it's a lot. To help, bottomNavView sits in xml main activity, collapsing toolbar sits in fragment in tab A, and the plain fragment class is just an example of when I switch to another tab, and the issue occurs. @GrayCygnus

Comment: have you find solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

on your CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

when you switch to tab with collapsing toolbar and

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

when switch to another

Answer (score 0):

Try to put

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

as the root of all the other fragments you are loading from the BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a custom toolbar in the profile fragment,you put this code to `onCreateView` method:

```
((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I had the same problem and this was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`
from root `CoordinatorLayout`.